# Recursive code for maximum height of a binary tree

Tags: recursion, tree

I came across a recursive code for calculating the maximum height of a binary tree-

```
int maxDepth(struct node* node)
{
  if (node==NULL)
     return 0;
  else
   {
     /* compute the depth of each subtree */
     int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left);
     int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right);

     /* use the larger one */
     if (lDepth > rDepth)
       return(lDepth+1);
    else return(rDepth+1);
   }
}
```

I'm tried to write the code in another way-

```
    int maxDepth(struct node* node)
 {
    if (node==NULL)
     return 0;
    else
    {
     /* compute the depth of each subtree */
     int lDepth = 1+maxDepth(node->left);  //notice the change
     int rDepth = 1+maxDepth(node->right); //notice the change

     /* use the larger one */
     if (lDepth > rDepth)
       return(lDepth);
    else return(rDepth);
   }
}
```

I'm confused whether both versions will work similarly or is there a bug in the second implementation.
I tried out few cases, for which both functions returned same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arithmetically they are the same, it doesn't matter when you add the 1 to the answer because no other arithmetic transformations are being done to the value which gets returned.  Technically yours is slightly less efficient because you do two additions, then throw away the smaller of the two values which wastes the work done on that one.  In reality I doubt you'd ever notice the difference if you did timings.

Answer (score -1):

These two `C` functions will behave identically.  All you have done in your rewrite of the function `maxDepth()` is to add 1 to the variables `lDepth` and `rDepth`.  However, you effectively undo that change by subtracting 1 from these variables in your return value:

```
int lDepth = 1+maxDepth(node->left);  // you added one to lDepth
int rDepth = 1+maxDepth(node->right); // you added one to rDepth

/* use the larger one */
if (lDepth > rDepth)
  return(lDepth);                     // but you subtract one here
else return(rDepth);                  // and you also subtract one here
```